# help troubleshooting deadlocks in sql server database

Tags: sql-server-2008, deadlock

I've got two database servers, 
 (1) production 
 (2) test

on the production database I get frequent deadlocks and I'm trying to find out what is causing it.

I take a backup of the database in production and restore it in test and when I perform the exact same scenario that yields deadlocks on the production server I am unable to reproduce in test.

any ideas/tips/hints would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you use SQL Profiler / SQL Trace to trace the deadlock graph event then post the *.xdl into your question?

Comment: Are the servers identical? Same # of procs? Could be deadlocks from parallelism if prod has more procs than test.

Comment: @SqlACID the prod has many more cores than test, how do I move forward on finding out if this can cause problems?

Comment: [Use the trace Luke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188246.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy solution that works in all cases but you might find it helpful to enable snapshot isolation. That way, transactions which are strictly readers do not participate in locking at all. This usually removes a lot of trouble. Google will show you how to do it (it is easy).